# Publication date of this Jimmy Hatlo cartoon

Tags: 1940s, photo-dating, wisconsin

This cartoon is on the back side of a photograph in a newspaper of a family member. The article is about him joining the military, around 1942/3. I can’t find a date on either side. Can someone determine the publication date of the Jimmy Hatlo cartoon? The newspaper was most likely located in Oshkosh Wisconsin.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cartoon by Jimmy Hatlo is one of his "[They'll Do It Every Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They%27ll_Do_It_Every_Time)" series, which ran in multiple newspapers around the U.S. from 1929 to 2008. (Other illustrators took over after Hatlo's death in 1963.)

This particular cartoon ran on **February 20, 1942**. I found it in the Buffalo (N.Y.) Evening News and the Syracuse (N.Y.) Herald-Journal by searching the [Fulton History](https://fultonhistory.com/Fulton.html) archived newspapers site for `jimmy hatlo AND "cooking dinner" AND (filename contains (1940~~1945))`.

[image: Jimmy Hatlo's They'll Do It Every Time cartoon from Feb 20, 1942]

[FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Wisconsin_Newspapers) has some information on where you can find Wisconsin newspapers, since you're interested in what's on the back of this cartoon in a specific newspaper.

NewspaperArchive.com has the [Oshkosh Daily Northwestern](https://newspaperarchive.com/browse/us/wi/oshkosh/) for years 1872-1975, but 1941-1951 are missing.